# Drawing a function in R over a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

Currently, I have some data, say they are stored in a `data.frame` as `data$y` and `data$x`. I have a regression over this data, in the form `log(y) = a + bx + cx^2`, using `fit <- lm(log(data$y) ~ data$x + I(data$x^2), data=data)`.

I have plotted a scatterplot with the function `plot(log(data$y), data$x)`.

```
fit <- lm(log(data$y) ~ data$x + I(data$x^2), data=data)
plot(log(data$y), data$x)
# what goes here to plot the fit?
```

How do I plot a curve of this form on the plot? Is there an easy way to plot it, by, say some function which simply allows plotting of a curve over a scatterplot?

Comment: I am a bit confused. You have 2 variables in your model essentially (x and x^2) but you try to plot the fitted values on top of a scatter plot of just x vs y? I can't see why. Use `par(new = TRUE); plot(<whatever else>)` to overlay plots, but I can't see the rational behind the problem you describe here.

Comment: @LyzandeR - I'd just use `lines()` or `curve()` to add another line to a plot. Using a whole new `plot()` is likely to mess up the labels and axes.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a built-in function (that I know of), but `predict()` + `lines()` is pretty simple.

Set up example:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
dd$y <- with(dd,exp(rnorm(100,mean=2+3*x-x^2,sd=0.5)))
```

Fit: (note you should *not* use `data$` in your formula)

```
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ x + I(x^2), data=dd)
```

Plot:

```
plot(log(y)~x,data=dd)
```

Add predictions:

```
newx <- seq(min(dd$x),max(dd$x),length.out=100)
lines(newx,predict(fit,newdata=data.frame(x=newx)))
```

[image]

You can use `dd$x` directly instead of constructing `newx`, but evenly spaced points will be nicer when your predictor variable is sparse and/or irregular.

Another possibility is `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(x,log(y)))+geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x+I(x^2))
```

[image]